# Forcing an integer type in Ansible Jinja2 filters

Tags: ansible

I have the following YAML in an Ansible playbook:

```
offset: "{{ publicip | regex_replace('^.*\\.([0-9]+)$', '\\\\1') | int % (step-1) + 1 }}"
cron_minute_list: "{% for i in range(offset, 60, step) %}{{ i }},{% endfor %}"
```

But when I run the playbook, I get this error:

```
fatal: [default] => Failed to template */{{ cron_minute_list | regex_replace('.$', '') }}:
  Failed to template {% for i in range(int_offset, 60, step) %}{{ i }},{% endfor %}:
    an unexpected type error occurred. Error was an integer is required
```

I get other errors when I try using `int(offset)` in the `range` statement. Appending a `| int` to the end of the `offset` declaration makes no difference.

There seems to be no way to set the type of `offset` to be an integer rather than a string. How can I fix this?

If there's another way to make such a cron schedule, so I don't have to worry about this, that would also be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can tell, you're trying to introduce a random splay to your cron minute using the IP of the machine. Ansible has a simple `random` filter that I think would be perfectly suited. Couple that with the `cron` module and your playbook should be radically simpler.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/cron_module.html
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#random-number-filter

```
cron_minute: {{ 59 | random(step=10) }}
...
- cron: name="do something" minute="{{ cron_minute }}" job="echo 'I am but a lowly cron job.'"
```